# Can WPF apps be compiled to native code?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, clr

I know there are tools like Salamander that can compile a .NET WinForms apps to fully native code with no need for the CLR/.NET Framework to be on a machine. Is this possible for WPF apps as well?

Comment: Salamander...for all those Windows machines without the .NET framework installed (Win98/2k?)

Comment: So Salamander works with WPF as well as WinForms? That's my question.

Comment: you could just specify your app requires WPF - I'm sure WPF works a lot faster than something trying to guess the direct-x calls it's making

Comment: @Chris S: Even if it was compiled to native, it still wouldn't work on 98/2k, since many of the API requirements weren't supported in those Operating Systems....

Comment: Thanks, I don't care about those OSes at all. Maybe this could work, but the comment below raises some questions.

Comment: Correction: According to Salamander's web site, Salamander-compiled code **does** require the CLR/.NET Framework installed on the target machine. All Salamander really does is change standard IL into Salamander's own proprietary "native code" format, so it can't be decompiled without a Salamander-specific decompilation tool. The code still runs on the CLR and uses the regular NET Framework libraries.

Comment: Ray, that is incorrect. http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/ It completely removes the need for .NET on the target machine. I think you're thinking of their obfuscator. "Starting from .NET 2.0, a native compilation feature will be introduced to compile all managed assemblies into x86 machine code, and thus improves performance and stops disassembling and decompilation. Not even a single MSIL instruction will be ever delivered to your customers."

Comment: Ray, not sure if your correction is in response to my previous comment, but their site plainly states that their tool results in x86 machine code. Are you suggesting that they're not being totally clear in how it works?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/protector.html), Salamander supports .NET Framework 3.5, which would suggest that WPF is supported.

That being said, I've yet to see a tool like this that supports WPF **well**.  There is much in WPF that is handled via runtime object metadata.

In addition, trying to avoid the need to install the CLR typically causes more problems than it solves.  Having the CLR installation be a requirement should not be a problem, especially now, for any reasonable application.

Comment: Well I'm also concerned about reverse engineering, which is so easy with MSIL vs. native code.

Comment: @Rhubarb: In this case, I'd use an obfuscator, instead of trying to go to native code.  The metadata is what makes reverse engineering easier - and there are very good decompilers for native code.  A good obfuscator raises the bar enough that I personally wouldn't worry about it, and doesn't "break" WPF...

Comment: Hex-Ray's IDA-Pro works for most things: http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/  There are some other ones out there, if you search... It's all about raising the bar, since nothing makes it impossible...

Comment: It seems native + obfuscation would beat MSIL + obfuscation, am I wrong?

Comment: Depends.  Native + Obfuscation is probably a bit tougher to decompile... However, it's also slower to develop.  Much of the power and flexibility of .NET comes from having the metadata available, though - so giving that up (which happens if you go native) has some dramatic disadvantages.  In specific, expect it to completely break WPF - since WPF uses TypeDescriptors everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a Viewmodel approach with the WPF logic all mapped through to native business logics with command and property binding using C++/CLI, as I described in a [presentation last year](http://aussiedesignedsoftware.com/blog/?p=130).